# Uploading a file to S3 with angular + aws-sdk-js + pre-signed url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I would like to use a pre-signed url with the aws-sdk-js and I can't find anywhere an example, is it possible to do something like this?

```
var bucket = new AWS.S3({uri: preSignedUrl});  <== ??
var params = {Key: 'my.key', Body: file};
bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
...
});
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have been given a presigned url, you don't actually need to use the AWS JavaScript SDK to use it.

In nodejs, for example, you could use the request module to upload a file using a presigned url.
Example:

```
request({
  url: presignedUrl,
  method: 'PUT',
  body: FILE
});
```

Noticed you're using Angular.  You could accomplish the same using an AJAX call as well.